# SignalR fork that supports Websocket on Windows 7

Tags: websocket, signalr

I used Socket.io on Node on and I like it.

I would like to use SignalR. But I heard WebSocket is not supported on Windows 7, which I use. I did some search and seems the reason is that WebSocket uses some Windows lib to handle WebSocket TCP.

But since SignalR is opensource on Github and Websocket is technically possible on Windows 7, I am wondering if there is or could be a fork of SignalR that support WebSocket on Windows 7. If not, is there any technical or legal reason?

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are not supported in Windows 7 if you are using ASP.NET. The only public implementations of client and server WebSockets are supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Here are the requirements to use websockets:

- The WebSocket Protocol was introduced in IIS 8.0.
- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.